# error TS2740: Type 'Observable<DocumentData>' is missing the following properties from type 'ProjectPage[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angularfire

I'm not sure how to fix this error. I've seen some posts, but I still haven't gotten to the answer to this problem, I'm guessing it's pretty easy, but I'm pretty new to Angular and really have no idea on how to fix it.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { ProjectPage } from './project-page';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-page',
  templateUrl: './project-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-page.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectPageComponent implements OnInit {

  project$: ProjectPage[];
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.project$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params) => {
        const name = params.get('name');
        return this.afs.doc('projects/' + name).ref.get()
        .then((doc) => {
          return doc.data();
        })
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem here is your typing. You specify `project$` to be of type `ProjectPage[]` but by using the route paramMap you are assigning it to an Observable. The typings would probably work if you change

`project$: ProjectPage[];`

to

`project$: Observable<ProjectPage[]>;`

Answer (score 0):

```
this.item$ = collectionData(collect) as Observable<Item[]>
```